# Slicing Series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the `Series` `obj`:

```
In [50]: obj = Series(np.arange(6,10), index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

In [51]: obj
Out[51]: 
a    6
b    7
c    8
d    9
dtype: int64
```

I'd like to take a slice of `obj`, and I can do that in a couple of ways:

```
In [52]: obj[1:3]
Out[52]: 
b    7
c    8
dtype: int64

In [53]: obj['b' : 'c']
Out[53]: 
b    7
c    8
dtype: int64
```

Now consider the `DataFrame` `param_estimates_good`:

```
In [54]: param_estimates_good
Out[54]: 
             a         b     sigma      a_se      b_se  sigma_se  success
1968  0.648508  1.803889  0.498017  0.784340  0.082366  0.529649        1
1972  0.539485  1.733304  0.451311  1.084170  0.174030  0.677134        1
1973  1.205704  2.054114  1.465606  0.095780  0.052851  0.090562        1
1974  1.398968  2.105287  2.029865  0.451929  0.056154  0.428696        1
1975  1.570900  1.877486  2.016978  0.186177  0.052413  0.183577        1
1976  0.688932  1.651232  0.874860  0.065038  0.099080  0.055247        1
1977  0.816918  1.949563  0.691899  0.516742  0.083973  0.385799        1
1980  0.730454  2.569974  2.297921  0.619403  0.157950  0.439383        1
1986  1.053362  1.770256  1.115229  0.235353  0.063867  0.202970        1
1993  2.531327  1.235418  2.005588  0.107785  0.011513  0.060647        1
1994 -0.759318  2.556910  0.175695  0.052099  0.078433  0.044315        1
1998  1.007787  1.548161  0.911332  2.538235  0.040285  2.001148        1
2000 -0.693261  1.518839 -0.290453  3.763934  1.329302  0.868444        1
2001  0.662391  0.650003  0.854752  0.550188  0.547999  0.376354        1
2002  0.652630  0.424864  0.524909  0.413478  0.334703  0.251172        1
2004 -0.169553  1.290054 -0.040504  0.279700  0.093937  0.115120        1
2005  0.146209  1.610219 -0.233461  0.171832  0.083844  0.123676        1
2007 -0.301397  0.822584  0.309423  1.119639  0.860818  0.377673        1
2008  1.334283  0.065856  1.704950  0.462811  0.489639  0.427041        1
2009  2.082782 -0.727128  1.072343  0.464726  0.093574  0.472603        1
2010  2.309353 -1.202509  0.906165  0.037950  0.080356  0.031981        1
2013  3.490101 -2.033734  1.468027  0.251317  0.030869  0.259732        1
2014  1.820431 -1.961015 -0.050831  0.262710  0.176057  0.266525        1
2016  1.818855 -0.580492  0.312369  0.450659  0.065661  0.474896        1
```

I take a slice of this to form a `Series` `g`:

```
In [55]: g = param_estimates_good['a']

In [56]: g
Out[56]: 
1968    0.648508
1972    0.539485
1973    1.205704
1974    1.398968
1975    1.570900
1976    0.688932
1977    0.816918
1980    0.730454
1986    1.053362
1993    2.531327
1994   -0.759318
1998    1.007787
2000   -0.693261
2001    0.662391
2002    0.652630
2004   -0.169553
2005    0.146209
2007   -0.301397
2008    1.334283
2009    2.082782
2010    2.309353
2013    3.490101
2014    1.820431
2016    1.818855
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

The `Index` of `g` are ints...

```
In [57]: g.index
Out[57]: 
Int64Index([1968, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1980, 1986, 1993, 1994,
            1998, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2013,
            2014, 2016],
           dtype='int64')
```

... so I try to slice `g` in an analagous way to to `obj`:

```
In [58]: g[0:7]
Out[58]: 
1968    0.648508
1972    0.539485
1973    1.205704
1974    1.398968
1975    1.570900
1976    0.688932
1977    0.816918
Name: a, dtype: float64


In [59]: g[1968 : 1977]
Out[59]: Series([], Name: a, dtype: float64)
```

Why does the latter method return an empty `Series`?

Answer (score 3):

I think it wants to find rows from position `1968` to `1977`, because it selects rows by positions - [`Slicing ranges [] in docs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#slicing-ranges):

> With Series, the syntax works exactly as with an ndarray, returning a slice of the values and the corresponding labels

It is same as [`Selection by position in docs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position) with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

```
print g.iloc[1968 : 1977]
Series([], Name: a, dtype: float64)
```

With [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) it works perfectly [`Selection By Label in docs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label):

```
print g.loc[1968 : 1977]
1968    0.648508
1972    0.539485
1973    1.205704
1974    1.398968
1975    1.570900
1976    0.688932
1977    0.816918
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

it's simple cause the `index` function is trying to call "**label of index**" not the "**position of index**" **unless** you specified it like `g.index(1968)`. turns out the correct one you should call it by `g[0:7]` / your previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

You get an empty Series because when using the slicing operator as in g[1968:1977], these are taken as locations (row indexes running from 0 to (N-1), where N is the size/length of the Series) and you seem to have 24 rows in g, so when you ask for all elements between locations 1968 and 1977 you get nothing (your last location is 23).

You want to use instead the g.index labels as in g.loc[1968:1977] and then you get all elements between labels 1968 and 1977 (inclusive).